# Select SQL datarow via cookie

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, cookies

I am updating our company website and want to change from using JS cookies to declare all data for dynamic content, to setting just the primary key so I can select a single datarow from a SQL DB.

I have dabbled in VB/SQL in XtraReports but not in a web environment, and am having trouble getting any clear & simple hints how to select a data row via the primary key in a cookie. I then need to extract the various data from that row using the column name.

Any help or guidance greatly received.

Comment: There are two parts to that question. One is getting the ID from the cookie. If you're already using cookies then presumably you know how to get extract data from one. The other part is querying the data by primary key, and finding information on that is dead easy. Once you have an ID, where it came from is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can set a cookie via JS and read it via VB, but I don't know how I actually link to the SQL DB in the first place. I was led to believe I need to declare a SQL connection on each aspx page before I can access that data?

Comment: There's loads of information around about connecting to database and retrieving and saving data from a VB.NET app. If you're not willing to do the research then that's on you. We're not here to teach you how program. We're here to help with specific issues. If you haven't even tried to connect to the database yet then you haven't encountered a specific issue. "I don't know how to do X, you tell me" is not appropriate for SO.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I disagree with your statement but you seem pretty helpful elsewhere. In fact, http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases illustrates the problem succinctly - I just noticed it's actually your post!  
In 18 years of extensive work work in-house for my business (inc. VB/SQL/JS) I have never had to post to a website like SO - so the documentation relevant to what I am doing is far from ubiquitous.  
I am not asking for anyone to write any code for me, but I will use the code in the url above as a hint - hopefully!!

Comment: SO and VBForums are two different types of sites. Personally, I expect people who post at VBForums to do a bit of research too but SO specifically requires it. Thee are questions that I would answer there but not here.

Comment: Evidently ignorance is not a defence.. my bad - I've sorted connection now using assistance elsewhere.

Comment: It's not about a defence. Ignorance is the reason. I'm providing you with information to correct that ignorance. If you're doing the wrong thing, would you rather that it wasn't pointed out and thus you never have reason to post better questions that are more likely to get answers? That's rhetorical, so no answer required.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Request.Cookies Collection to read cookies from Request.

```
if(Request.Cookies["key"]!=null)
{
    var value=Request.Cookies["key"].Value;
}
```

Request.Cookies is always present with each request. and then get the Information into a DataSet from DataBase. You may Read the Dataset using below:

if ds is your DataSet , then

```
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
     foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
     {
         var data=dr["ColumnName"];
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I can set the cookie and get that info via VB, but what I need to learn is how to query the other column data from that same row.

Comment: i have edited my answer to include how to read results from a dataset and different columns in a row.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I have declared a SQLDataSource table on the aspx page, but after translating your code to VB I get syntax errors when I paste it into my existing code behind, so I obviously have something missing or wrong. Once I have that sorted, I should be good to go.
 
Just to give specifics; sqlDataSource.ID = SqlDataSource1, tablename.ID = Veneerlist, primaryKey.ID = SortName.

I need to run: Select * where SqlDataSource1.Veneerlist.SortName = #cookievalue#
I will then use the other data via its column name, e.g. Description, Width, Price